# dpkg: error: dpkg status database is locked by another process

Tags: ubuntu, locking, dpkg

Delete the updates with:
cd /var/lib/dpkg/updates
sudo rm *

Tried to update and upgrade:
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade

Still it says that:
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock
This means that some program is blocking the system or installing a new software.

Check if any programs is locking dpkg file:

ps aux | grep -i apt

try to see which are existing locks

sudo lsof /var/lib/dpkg/lock
sudo lsof /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
sudo lsof /var/cache/apt/archives/lock

Try to delete them using:

sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
Try again:

sudo dpkg --configure -a
It should work.

Try again to installing with:

sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
This should resume the process and keep everything stable.

this way it resolved my issue of dbpkg is locked

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

List locks using:

```
lsof /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

Then check if any process is running:

```
ps cax | grep PID
```

If any process is running kill it:

```
kill PID
```

#wait
kill  PID

```
ps cax | grep PID
```

Remove the lock file:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

Fix dpkg :

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

This way it resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is fixed for me by making ensure there should be no installation process running.
I was installing vscode by dpkg command.
also installing via terminal. So I stopped the terminal installation process of vs code.